# Is it wrong to answer a question that you've voted to close?

Tags: discussion

I'm no longer a regular on this site. But, in the past I frequently would answer a question for one of the lost souls who accidentally stumbled onto the kllling floor.

These questions are usually ELL quality questions which have easy answers to a native speaker.

Is this wrong?  I feel that I'm doing proper duty by voting to close and explaining in the comments why I did so. But, answering the question feels like the neighborly thing to do.

I'm asking because someone commented on my having done so.

Comment: Related: **1.** [Roses are red, apples are green](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4306/roses-are-red-apples-are-green?rq=1) **2.** [“This question appears to be off topic because it is better asked on ELL.”](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4249/this-question-appears-to-be-off-topic-because-it-is-better-asked-on-ell?noredirect=1&lq=1) **3.** [Why are answers being posted in the comments on the question?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2653/why-are-answers-being-posted-in-the-comments-on-the-question)

Comment: **4.** [People answering off-topic questions: What should we do?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1757/people-answering-off-topic-questions-what-should-we-do) **5.** [New users answering off-topic questions from other new users](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11033/new-users-answering-off-topic-questions-from-other-new-users?rq=1) And more recently, **6.** [It’s September again](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13392/it-s-september-again)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you cast a vote to place a question *on hold* because it's off-topic, and then you post an answer. What is the message you are sending?

1. You *know* that the question is too basic for EL&U, so you cast your vote to migrate it to ELL. In the meantime you post an answer, if the OP is migrated, the answer will remain useful for the ELL community.
2. You *think* the question is off-topic and cast a vote to close it but you feel sorry for the OP because you understand where their dilemma is stemming from, so you post an answer that will only be useful to the OP and no one else.
3. You *know* the question is off-topic, so you do the right thing and cast a vote to place it *on hold*. However, you also post an answer: that way the OP gets an answer and everyone is happy. As an added bonus, the next time the OP posts *another* off-topic question on EL&U they can be confident knowing that someone will post an answer even if their question gets closed because that's how we roll on EL&U. [Wash, rinse, repeat](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/rinse_repeat)

If you don't vote to close…

4. You *know* the question is off-topic, but you don't cast a vote to close it. Instead, you post an answer; the OP receives their answer and added bonus, you earn easy reputation points.

**Answer 1. is acceptable**.
Answers 2-4 are well-intentioned, misguided, harmful and/or counterproductive.

Comment: I realize the (3) is tongue in cheek but I worry that not everyone will see that and take this as “the right process for ELU”

Comment: Ok, I trust you then. +1.

Comment: Is it reasonable to expect users to behave in a way SE disincentivises?